# Is this tail recursive?

Tags: scheme, tail-recursion

Per my understanding of tail recursion, the following function is not a tail recursive function.

```
(define (map f L)
  (if (null? L)
    '()
    (cons (f (car L)) (map f (cdr L)))))
```

`cons` will have to wait until `(map f (cdr L))` returns to finish its job. That prevents it from being tail recursive.

Am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's not tail recursive.

Tail recursion is when the recursive call is in the tail position. The call to generate the return should be the original function or a mutually tail recursive function like so

```
(define (even? int)
  (if (= 0 int) #t (odd? (- int 1))))

(define (odd? int)
  (if (= 1 int) #t
      (if (= 0 int) 
          #f
          (even? (- int 1)))))
```

Comment: I believe you meant the second function to be `odd`. Thanks.

Comment: `(or (= 0 int) (odd? …))`

Answer (score 5):

Yes!

That answer apparently wasn't long enough for Stack Exchange.

Yes, with a cherry on top!

Comment: That's a correct answer but a little explanation would be needed to make it a really good answer...

Comment: @John, I was hesitant about my conclusion after I saw that function in [the lecture notes from a CS class] (http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~fischer/cs538.s08/lectures/Lecture16.4up.pdf).

Answer (score 4):

It is safe to assume that it is not tail recursive since the standard (RNRS, including the latest R7RS) doesn't require [*tail recursion modulo cons*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_recursion_modulo_cons) optimization.

That of course doesn't deny anyone from actually implementing TRMCO in their Scheme implementation so that your definition of `map`, which is *almost* tail recursive (except for that *`cons`*), really would become tail recursive.  Such an implementation could  achieve this by transforming your code to something similar to the code below:

```
#!r6rs
(import (except (rnrs) map)
        (rnrs mutable-pairs))

(define (map fun lst)
  (define result (cons 'head '()))
  (let loop ((tail result) (lst lst))
    (cond ((null? lst) (cdr result))
          (else (set-cdr! tail (cons (fun (car lst)) '()))
                (loop (cdr tail) (cdr lst))))))
```

The transformation is pretty straightforward so I really don't see why Scheme implementations don't do it automatically, when Prolog does. It's less complex than what an implementation needs to do to support `syntax-rules` or `call-with-current-continuation`.

Comment: I wasn't trying to implement my own `map`. It was just an example to seek clarification on what is a tail recursive function and what is not. Thanks for the answer anyway.

Comment: @RSahu You did get that I'm talking about Scheme doing the transformation right? eg. you write what you have in your question and it rewrites it to something similar to mine? It's perfectly doable as Prolog has it.

Comment: no I think I am failing to understand the crux of your answer.

Comment: any mention of TRMC gets automatic up-vote from me! ;)

Comment: @RSahu it means that in the presence of TRMC optimization your code would be automatically transformed by a compiler into the code as shown, which *is* tail-recursive. So you *could* just write such code without worries. :)

Comment: btw here the head-sentinel trick isn't needed: it's needed when the inclusion of elements is conditional (like with filter). but here the start is simple: `(fun (car lst))` is always included in result. So it itself can be used as the sentinel. -- In general I think TRMC is more complex to do in Scheme than in Prolog because in Scheme there are many functions that construct lists, not just `cons`; plus it should apply for other monoid types too (w/ associative construction, a+(b+c)=(a+b)+c). -- Prolog does it only for lists, too.